# Why boost::fiber blocks?

Tags: c++, boost, fiber

I'm trying to play with [boost::fiber](https://github.com/olk/boost-fiber) library but I have the problem with the "Hello, World" example. In the following code the program flow blocks after the fiber is finished and the main function never returns.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/fiber/all.hpp>

using namespace std;

void helloFiber()
{
  cout << "Hello, boost::fiber" << endl;
}

int main()
{
  boost::fibers::fiber f(helloFiber);

  cout << "Before join." << endl;
  f.join();
  cout << "After join." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The result is:

> Before join.
>   Hello, boost::fiber

I built [boost::fiber](https://github.com/olk/boost-fiber) current develop branch with the current develop branch of [modular-boost](https://github.com/boostorg/boost). Is this behavior bug in the current implementation or there is something wrong in my usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your test app prints:

Before join.
Hello, boost::fiber
After join.

maybe you've checkout an broken version from branch develop

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
int main()
{
  boost::fibers::fiber f(helloFiber);
  f.detach();
  f.join();

  return 0;
}
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread.html

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting a answer. Your answer appears to get the job done, but you could improve your answer by providing a bit of context for your code (even just one complete sentence). You may find other tips at the [help page on answering question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This throws an instance of exception: **boost::fibers::fiber_resource_error**, since after detach the fiber is no longer in joinable state. The exact error message is  *boost fiber: fiber not joinable: Invalid argument*.

Comment: hmm i'll think i through next time. Sorry for my poor quality answer. I currently do not have a machine to test on.
Just one more thought: 
cout is not thread-safe. does your program complete if you remove the cout statements from the main routine and only keep the one in the fiber?

Comment: detach() followed by a join() is nonsense - after detaching `f` doesn't refer to a fiber

Comment: this is nonsense